# How to understand the following limit exist: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} f(X)^Tf(X)=?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

If I have a matrix $X\in R^{n\times d}$ and a function $f:  R^{n\times d} \to  R^{n\times d}$. How to understand the following limit exist:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} f(X)^Tf(X)=?$$

For example, if I consider a simple example of $X\in R^{n\times 1}$, and assume that
$$f(X)=[a_{11}, a_{21}, \dots, a_{n1}]^T\in R^{n\times 1}$$. Then

$$f(X)^Tf(X)=a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+\dots+a_{n1}^2$$. So the limit becomes the
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}(a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+\dots+a_{n1}^2)$$
So it is easy to understand for $d=1$. But how to understand $d\ge 2$?

A similar question is that how to understand the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\|X\|_F}{n}<\infty$$
where the $\|X\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Assuming the $n$ in $R^{n \times d}$ and the $n$ in the limit expression are different, then the limit is just $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} Y$, where $Y$ is a fixed $d \times d$ matrix that doesn't depend on $n$.

Comment: But there will be an index of $n$ of elements of $Y$, right? As the example for $d=1$.

Comment: Well, yes, but that would be the other $n$ (i.e. the $n$ in $R^{n \times d}$, not the $n$ in $\lim_{n \to \infty}$). It would be better to write the limit as $\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{m} f(X)^\top f(X)$, just so you can use a different dummy variable. Of course, this is all under the assumption that the two $n$s are indeed different. If they aren't, then the question doesn't make sense, unless $f$ is also a sequence of functions depending on $n$. If this is the case, then the limit will not necessarily be $0$ (depending on the functions $f_n$ and the matrix $X$).

Comment: @TheoBendit So you think the limit is zero?

Comment: I suspect so, yes. The problem is slightly malformed, and I have had to make a small assumption contrary to what you've written, in order to make sense of it. Under this assumption, the limit is definitely $0$. If my assumption is incorrect, then I don't know what is being asked, so I have no idea.

Comment: I guess the author does mean not zero in the original paper. For $d=1$, I have written it. So the limit makes sense for you, right? Can we understand for $d=2$ the limit exists means that the limit of each element of this 2 by 2 matrix exists?

Comment: It doesn't quite make sense to me, no. Your column vector $f(X)$ grows taller and taller with each $n$, even though the notation $f(X)$ suggests it shouldn't depend on $n$. But, maybe $f(X)$, despite the notation, does indeed grow with $n$, but then you are making the assumption that the next $f(X)$ is the same as the previous $f(X)$ but with an additional $a_{(n+1)1}$ appended on the bottom. I have no idea how justifiable this assumption you've made is, and the limit in this case would be equal to $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n1}^2$ (which may or may not be $0$).

Comment: @TheoBendit How about if I add $f(X)=[f_1(X), f_2(X), \dots, f_n(X)]^T\in R^{n\times d}$?

Comment: Yes, that does change things. It now means that the question at least makes sense. It's still not possible to determine if the given limit exists or what its value might be, but the question is well-formed. Now it depends (even in the $d = 1$ case) what the specific functions $f_n$ are.

Comment: @TheoBendit But if $n\to \infty$, can we apply $f$ to an infinite matrix? I am still confused about the notation $f_n(X)$ for n-th coordinate.

Comment: Actually, this comment made me realise I was wrong before. The $X$ is $n \times d$, which means $X$ cannot be a single matrix as $n$ increases, and it's unclear what the domain of the $f_i$s actually is. You're going to have to provide a lot more context, because so far, it's not really possible to discern what is meant by this notation.